# Is this the correct code for the defined problem?

Tags: c#

Can anybody help me with the of bit swapping in c#. It actually goes like this that the function accepts a number then it will convert it into binary and then swap its any bits and then convert it into decimal and the return the number.

Here is what I have tried:

```
DectoBin(int num) {
    stringBuilder strBin = new StringBuilder();
    while (num / 2 ! =1) {
        strBin.Append((num % 2).ToString());
        num = num / 2;
    }
    String str = strBin.ToString();
    int BinDec(string str)
    int DecNum = 0;
    for (int i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        DecNum = +DecNum
        int.parse(str[k++] * pow(2, i);
    }
    return DecNum;
}
```

I need c# code of this problem soon. If anybody can provide me the code, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*, please? E.g. what are the desired results for `0`, `1`, `5`, `7`, `8`, `-1`?

Comment: *Is this the correct code* does it produce the expected output?

Comment: Can you please fix your code? There are missing semi colons, missing return type, missing curly brackets and more

Comment: No it is not the correct code!! If num<=0, then the method will enter an infinite loop & never return.

Comment: There is too much wrong to even start fixing it. Please provide code that at least the compiler will accept and compile :)

Comment: i cannot produce the code. I tried to develop a logic only so if somebody can help me the correct code. I am not really good at coding

Answer (score 0):

Your question is *vague* one, however, I can provide some suggestions. First, let's represent the initial `int` as a convenient `string`:

```
  int value = ...

  // Meanful bits only : 5 -> "101" (without leading zeroes)
  string bits = Convert.ToString(unchecked((uint) value), 2); 

  // All 32 bits : 5 -> "00000000000000000000000000000101" 
  string allBits = Convert.ToString(unchecked((uint) value), 2).PadLeft(32, '0');
```

Time to query; let's use *Linq* whcih can be very convenient. Depending on what does *swap* mean it can be

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // reversed bits: "101" -> "101", "100" -> "001", etc.
  // but either "bits" or "allBits" as an argument 
  string result = string.Concat(bits.Reverse());
```

Or

```
  // each '0' truns into "1" and vice versa: "101" -> "010", "100" -> "011" etc
  // but either "bits" or "allBits" as an argument 
  string result = string.Concat(bits.Select(b => b == '1' ? '0' : '1'));
```

Finally, let's take `int` back with a help of `Convert`:

```
  int outcome = unchecked((int)Convert.ToUInt32(result, 2));
```

Comment: The code question basically is to convert a decimal number to binary and then swap one of its bits and then convert it back to decimal and print the final number.